# reference chem-acs style

Tags: biblatex

I dont know why the title of an article is not appearing in my reference. Maybe you could help me to find out.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[style=chem-acs]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{library.bib}
\begin{document}

hello\cite{Lieb}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

my reference is

```
@ARTICLE{Lieb,
  year = {2013},
  month = feb,
  publisher = {American Academy of Pediatrics },
  volume = {131},
  number = {3},
  pages = {e983, e985},
  author = {A. S. Lieberthal and A. E. Carroll and T. Chonmaitree and T. G. Ganiats and A. Hoberman and M. A. Jackson and M. D. Joffe and D. T. Miller and R. M. Rosenfeld and X. D. Sevilla and R. H. Schwartz and P. A. Thomas and D. E. Tunkel},
  title = {{T}he diagnosis and management of acute otitis media},
  journal = {Pediatrics},
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chemistry bibliography styles are famously terse and many omit the (often long) article title, because an article can easily be identified by journal, volume and page numbers.

But with most `biblatex-chem` styles you can turn the article title back on with `articletitle=true,`

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[style=chem-acs, articletitle=true]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Lieb,
  year    = {2013},
  month   = feb,
  volume  = {131},
  number  = {3},
  pages   = {e983, e985},
  author  = {A. S. Lieberthal and A. E. Carroll and T. Chonmaitree
             and T. G. Ganiats and A. Hoberman and M. A. Jackson
             and M. D. Joffe and D. T. Miller and R. M. Rosenfeld
             and X. D. Sevilla and R. H. Schwartz and P. A. Thomas
             and D. E. Tunkel},
  title   = {The diagnosis and management of acute otitis media},
  journal = {Pediatrics},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}

hello\cite{Lieb}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lieberthal, A. S.; Carroll, A. E.; Chonmaitree, T.; Ganiats, T. G.; Hoberman, A.; Jackson, M. A.; Joffe, M. D.; Miller, D. T.; Rosenfeld, R. M.; Sevilla, X. D.; Schwartz, R. H.; Thomas, P. A.; Tunkel, D. E. The diagnosis and management of acute otitis media. Pediatrics 2013, 131, e983, e985.]

Comment: You want to look at older literature: '`Ber., *40*, 1200`'

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `articletitle=true`

```
\usepackage[style=chem-acs,articletitle=true]{biblatex}
```